# How to query distinct months with it's data from the table using eloquent or raw query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have my table called attendance which have columns

```
Schema::create('attendances', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('school_registration_number');
        $table->integer('students')->default(0);
        $table->integer('books_borrowed')->default(0);
        $table->integer('fiction_english')->default(0);
        $table->integer('fiction_swahili')->default(0);
        $table->integer('chem')->default(0);
        $table->integer('bio')->default(0);
        $table->integer('geo')->default(0);
        $table->integer('math')->default(0);
        $table->integer('civ')->default(0);
        $table->integer('kis')->default(0);
        $table->integer('his')->default(0);
        $table->integer('eng')->default(0);
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('month');
        $table->string('year');
    });
```

And now I would like to query yearly report example 2017 where I can be able to fetch distinct months of the year and on each month row display  sum of students, sum of each  books borrowed  on that month of the year 2017

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to write query for my problem

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT month, sum(students) as students, sum(books_borrowed) as books_borrowed, sum(fiction_english) as feng,sum(fiction_swahili) as fkis,sum(chem) as chem,sum(bio) as bio, sum(geo) as geo,sum(math) as math, sum(civ) as civ,sum(kis) as kis,sum(his) as his,sum(eng) as eng
        FROM attendances
        WHERE year = $year AND school_registration_number = '$regno' GROUP BY month";
```

$result =  DB::select(DB::raw($sql));

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(students), COUNT(books_borrowed), month, year
FROM attendances
WHERE year = '2017'

SQL; 
$result = DB::select(DB::raw($sql));
```

Comment: It has thrown error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause (SQL: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(students), COUNT(books_borrowed), month, year FROM attendances WHERE year = "2017")

Comment: At the end of the query add `GROUP BY year` @TheodoryFaustine

Comment: this query return only only distinct months and year but without without summation of types books borrowed in particular year ob each month